# How to link favicon icon at Laravel

Tags: laravel, hyperlink, favicon

We know how to link HTML images and CSS files according to the following code.

```
{{ HTML::image('images/example.jpeg', 'Example Image') }}
{{ HTML::style('css/main.css') }}
```

But, how to link the favicon icon at Laravel as we can not do like a static HTML file?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

> For Laravel 5.xx

We can link favicon icon and css file in the following way. In Laravel application put your favicon icon and css file under the public folder. In my case, I put them public/css folder.

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.png') }}">
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

> For Laravel 6.00

```html
<link rel="icon" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/favicon.jpg') }}" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/app.css')  }}">
```

> For Laravel 8.00

```html
<link rel="icon" href="{{ url('css/favicon.jpg') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('css/style.css') }}">
```

Comment: I was also searching for solution of this problem. Unfortunately, Html builder was removed in Laravel 5 but laravelcollective.com has brought it back. By inspecting its source code, I found that there is a favicon method which we can use like this     `{!! Html::favicon('favicon') !!}`

Comment: The problem is that you can't use those methods in config files: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32167

Answer (score 30):

In laravel 5, the favicon.ico is in **public/favicon.ico** To change the favicon, just have to replace **public/favicon.ico** with yours.

Comment: It is. Only when I set up a fresh installation using `laravel new` the favicon.ico was not added properly. I mean, the file had zero bytes. First time I checked this out so not sure if this was a fluke. Anyways, you can replace that one with your own favicon.co. And when you restart the browser you will see it.

Comment: Hello, I know that I dont make the post, but this worked for me in localhost, what I have to do to work in a domain? PD: sorry for my english

Answer (score 10):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.ico') }}">
```

In blade we can use the assets like asset('img/favicon.ico') but they should be in {{...}} instead of {{{...}}}

Answer (score 4):

If you're using **LaravelCollective**

```
{{ Html::favicon( '/assets/images/favicon.ico' ) }}
```

You can see whole `Html` method in `/vendor/laravelcollective/html/src/HtmlBuilder`

**Edit:** Installation guide in [here](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html#installation).

Answer (score 3):

There's also other way to show it.

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ URL::to('fav icon link') }}"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a much better to add a manifest.json file in your public folder and add the different size of favicons in that folder too. Laravel will pick it up automatically.

example of manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Your app name",
    "short_name": "",
    "icons": [
        {
             "src": "favicon.ico",
             "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
             "type": "image/x-icon"
        },
        {
            "src": "android-chrome-256x256.png",
            "sizes": "256x256",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#ffffff",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "display": "standalone"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Default .ico favicon and best quality for modern browser .png favicon placed in /public/

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ asset('favicon.png') }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

for image inside public use:
title tag your title

followed

link rel='shortcut icon' href='public/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'

for image in other location inside public:

title tag your title

followed by

link rel='shortcut icon' href='public/pathtoicon/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'

Hope this will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

**If you're using laravelcollective/html**

```
{!! Html::favicon('public/images/favicon.ico') !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel **v10.41.0** you can simply put it in `./public/*`.

And import it like this:

```php
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

If `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}">` is not working, try: `<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}?v={{ time() }}">`

The addition of `?v={{ time() }}` to the URL is a cache-busting technique that can help bypass browser caching issues.