# Does anyone know how to change the favicon on the login screen in laravel?

Tags: laravel-8

I have it on all other areas of my site but when on my login or register screen, it's not showing

Comment: Already answered on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563580/how-to-link-favicon-icon-at-laravel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to link favicon icon at Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563580/how-to-link-favicon-icon-at-laravel)

Comment: I've tried those but it's not working on my login or register screen (i.e register.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

[image: guest.blade.php]

to change the favicon for login and register screens I had to change the img src in resources/views/layouts/guest.blade.php, and that basically changed it.